# The use of particle "de"

Tags: particle-で

> そんな素敵なライブにナレーションで参加させて頂けて本当に嬉しいです

What does that sentence mean? I'm confused with the use of particle "de" there. As far as I know, "de" is used to indicate location or time of action. And ナレーション is neither location nor time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This で is used for indicating "way","means","role". ナレーションで参加する means "to join something in a role of narration".

For example, 私は、エキストラで映画に出た(I appeared as an extra in a movie).

Comment: So it's "I'm happy to be participate in that live in a role of narration"? In that case, should we see narration as a verb or noun?

Comment: Yes, it means so. ナレーション is a noun and ナレーションする is a verb.